# Show function is equal to series

Tags: calculus

How do we show that the equation:

$$f(x) = \frac{9}{(x-1)(x+2)^2}$$

is equal to the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(-1)-\frac{{(-1)}^{n}}{2^{n+1}} - \frac{3(-1)^n(n+1)}{2^{n+2}}]x^n$$

I have tried differentiating it, but i feel that it is an incorrect approach. I am confused on the method which is required to be taken to solve this problem. The approach required to be taken for this problem is sufficient :)

This is part 2 of my question: [Find constants of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729350/find-constants-of-function) - Partial fraction decomposition

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the results of [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729350/find-constants-of-function/729353#729353).

Then,

$$f(x) = \frac{A}{(x-1)} + \frac{B}{(x+2)} + \frac{C}{(x+2)^{2}} $$
and use the fact that:
$$
 \frac 1{a-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{-n-1}x^n\\
\frac 1{(a-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a^{-n-2}x^n.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I have a question, what does the n reference to?

Comment: summations are from $n=0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Ah...got it!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  Use partial fractions to write
$$\frac{9}{(x-1)(x+2)^2}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{C}{x+2}$$
for constants $A,B,C$, then use known series for the terms on the right hand side.

Comment: You know what funny? His previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729350/find-constants-of-function

Comment: Very strange... I didn't see that because I just woke up, it's early morning where I am.  Anyway, glad I didn't spend 20 minutes writing the answer ;-)

Comment: Do you really need 20 minutes to figure that out?

Comment: I don't need 20 seconds to figure it out!  But if I had written more with the series expansions etc etc etc and fully explained it, it might have taken 20 minutes. . . maybe ;-)

Comment: @David Sorry, will add that link here. Just in case

Answer (score 0):

You already know partial fraction decomposition. Now consider $\frac{1}{x+a}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{a}}$ and expansion of geometric and binomial series.